# Efficient data storage, partitioning, and selection in d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm having trouble seeing the big picture for some potentially massive refactoring. I'm looking for a solution (if one exists) that solves two problems simultaneously. I haven't coded in d3 for a long time and was never fluent to begin with.

I've created a simple demo of MCMC. It looks like this:
[image: demo pic]

All the data exist in an array `thetas` that has dimensions `nChains` x `nIters`, or 2 x ... (with the chain length increasing with each mouse click).

**Now I want to show a burn-in, which will be the same length for each chain. For the left plot, the burn-in will show, in different colors (e.g., orange and red) for each chain, the first `biLength` points.** Effectively, the first `biLength` points that are already there will just be colored differently. **On the histogram on the right, I want those points to have their own corresponding bars.**

Should I create a separate array to hold the burn-in, effectively plotting two containers of data on each plot? (Is there an example of how to do this?) Alternatively, is there some way to keep the data in `thetas` but handle subcomponents differently? (Example?)

Here's some sample code to show how I'm currently plotting `thetas`:

```
// Left plot update
function movePoints ()
    { 
    var tmp = chart.selectAll(".vis1points").data(thetas[0], function (d, i) { return i; } );
    tmp
        .enter().insert("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "vis1points")
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(i); })
        .attr("cy", yy)
        .attr("r", 3)
    tmp.transition()
        .duration(10)
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(i); })
        .attr("cy", yy)
    tmp.exit()
        .transition().duration(10).attr("r",0).remove();

    if ( nChains == 2 ) {
        var tmp2 = chart.selectAll(".vis1points2").data(thetas[1], function (d, i) { return i; } );
        tmp2
        .enter().insert("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "vis1points2")
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(i); })
        .attr("cy", yy)
        .attr("r", 3)
        tmp2.transition()
        .duration(10)
        .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(i); })
        .attr("cy", yy)
        tmp2.exit()
        .transition().duration(10).attr("r",0).remove();
    }
    };
```

The axes currently take `thetas` as input to infer the range and domain limits.

For the histogram on the right:

```
 // Creation involves... 
    var dataLength = thetas[0].length;
    this.histBars = this.vis.selectAll("rect.vis2bars")
        .data(that.histVals.counts[0])
        .enter().append("svg:rect")
        .attr("class", "vis2bars")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return that.xx2(i); }) 
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[0])/dataLength)); })    
        .attr("height",function (d, i) { return that.yy2(0)-that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[0])/dataLength)); })
        .attr("width", Math.floor(innerWidth2/numBins));
    this.histBars.transition()
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[0])/dataLength)); })    
        .attr("height",function (d, i) { return that.yy2(0)-that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[0])/dataLength)); })
        .duration(dur);
```

And the update:

```
    this.update = function( dur2 ) {
    var dataLength = thetas[0].length;
    var tmp2 = this.histBars.data(this.histVals.counts[0]); 
    var tmp3;
    if ( nChains > 1 ) { // fix
        tmp3 = this.histBars2.data(this.histVals.counts[1]);
    }
    var that = this;
    tmp2
        .transition()
        .delay( 0 ) // could tweak...
        .duration(dur2 - 10)
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[0])/dataLength)); })    
        .attr("height",function (d, i) { return that.yy2(0)-that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[0])/dataLength)); }); 

    // Add update for second data set
    if ( nChains > 1 ) {
        tmp3
        .transition()
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[1])/dataLength)); })    
        .attr("height",function (d, i) { return that.yy2(0)-that.yy2(that.maxDensity*(d/dataLength)/(d3.max(that.histVals.counts[1])/dataLength)); }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the color of your circles when updating them, for example inside here :

```
tmp.transition()
    .duration(10)
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(i); })
    .attr("cy", yy)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
         if (d.isBiLengthPoint) {
              return "orange";
         } else {
              return "blue";
         }
     });
```

I assume that for the moment you are coloring your circles based on your CSS, but for the effect you want I really think that loading them dynamically is a better solution.

Or you could change the class of your circles dynamically and have two CSS classes declaration

```
tmp.transition()
    .attr("class", function(d) {
         if (d.isBiLengthPoint) {
              return "vis1points-bilength";
         } else {
              return "vis1points";
         }
     })
    .duration(10)
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return xx(i); })
    .attr("cy", yy)
```

and in your CSS

```
 vis1points {
     fill: blue;
 }
 vis1points-bilength {
     fill: orange;
 }
```